# What is the best way to check if a value exists in a database in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net

I am familiar with connecting to databases in VB.NET to get data, but I have a slightly different task this time. In the past I have hit the database to get values from a table to use in my application (names, addresses, prices, etc.), but now I need to simply access the database to check and see if a value exists. I don't know the best way to go about this. Is there a good, efficient way to do this without actually getting any data from the database?

To further clarify, I want to check and see if a certain code exists in the database when the user enters a value in a textbox (this is an ASP.NET web site project). If the code exists, I will inform the user via a popup box.

EDIT:

If I create a stored procedure in SQL Server that returns true if the value exists or false if it doesn't (or 0 or 1), how can I use the return value in VB.NET?

Comment: You could do something like `select count(*) as RecordCount from table where column = something` and then perform logic in your VB app based upon the `RecordCount` returned.

Comment: Can you tell us which database are you using? There are different ways to this task depending on the db and someone of them are really fast others are not really recommended if you have a lot of records

Comment: @Steve It's a SQL Server database. I thought I mentioned that. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the Primary Key value or some other unique value of your table the fastest way I know to check the existence or not of a particular record is the following

```
Dim cmdText = "IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM yourTable WHERE idField = @value) " & _
              "SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0"

Using cnn = new SqlConnection(.....)
Using cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cnn)
    cnn.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 9876
    Dim result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    Dim exists = IF result = 1, True, False
    ....
End Using
End Using
```

This approach is preferable to count the records that match your condition because the database engine is free to return immediately after checking if the condition has been matched instead of counting till the end of the table. But, of course, it is of the utmost importance that the field on which you execute the search is indexed.

Some info on the [EXISTS operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm going to test it now.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to call this VB.NET function from the client side, would you (JavaScript)?

Comment: Sorry no, I know very little of JavaScript

Comment: Good solution, although using an `IF EXISTS` is a little overboard as it needs to sort and fully scan the table. A simple select would suffice in this case **or** a `count`. For ex: `SELECT 1
FROM table
WHERE idField = @value`

Comment: @zaggler And if the where is not matched? This would return a NULL thus complicating the client side code (I think)

Comment: @Steve it returns 0, just tested this. Edit: it returns 0 for the count function. Nothing if using the select with the where clause.

Comment: Uhm, you are correct, strange I have always given for granted the ExecuteScalar returns a NULL if the match condition fails.

Comment: Ah, got it now, it is the Convert.ToInt32 that makes the zero

Comment: OK mistery solved but I am curious about the sort and full scan you mentioned before. [In this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx) they argue very convincingly to use  the IF EXISTS  approach

Answer (score 3):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTableName WHERE CODE = @CODE

Comment: Nice solution, the execution plan is better.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something here as it seems too easy! It sounds like all you want is to execute a simple SQL query along the lines of Select Field from Table where field = Value. The Command execution should return the number of rows selected so if Return is greater than 0 then the item exists.

You feed the Value with the item entered in the textbox when the SQL Command is constructed at run time.

Apologies if I'm missing summit!

VB.net KB on running stored procs from VB.net:-

[Running SPs from VB.net](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308049)

Comment: I should have been more clear. Your answer is not wrong; I was just wondering if this would be the best way of achieving the goal. I am going to edit the question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No Probs - I'll have a wander into me computer cave and load up VB to gi'e me an example of executing an SP as a function - it is easy but I can't  remember syntax off the top o' me head - getting old!